# Django Rest Framework - Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API using Django Rest Framework. I'm trying to list or create an "Order" object, but when i'm trying to access the console gives me this error:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

**Views:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, YAMLRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from order.models import *
from API.serializers import *
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Order
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

**And my URLs:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.functional import curry
from django.views.defaults import *
from rest_framework import routers
from API.views import *

admin.autodiscover()

handler500 = "web.views.server_error"
handler404 = "web.views.page_not_found_error"

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'orders', OrdersViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
)
```

And then I'm using this command in the console:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/ -H 'Authorization: Token 12383dcb52d627eabd39e7e88501e96a2sadc55'
```

And the error say:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Comment: Try this: `curl -H "Authorization: Token 12383dcb52d627eabd39e7e88501e96a2sadc55"  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/`

Comment: Same error. Authentication credentials were not provided

Comment: In my case this happened due to a teammate switching the user to inactive mode.

Comment: Try to read [Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) first.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Solved by adding "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES" to my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
   ),
}
```

Comment: Thought I did this, but I had added `'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'` to `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` instead of `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I don't understand however why I didn't get the "Authentication credentials were not provided." error when making the request with Postman, whereas I *did* get the error when my Angular client made requests. Both with the same token in the Authorization header...

Comment: `SessionAuthentication` is enabled by default and works with the standard session cookies, so it's likely that your Angular (or other JS framework) application was working because of the default session authentication.

Answer (score 220):

If you are running Django on Apache using mod_wsgi you have to add

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

in your `httpd.conf`. Otherwise, the authorization header will be stripped out by `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: In case if you are wondering where to write this, follow the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340534/how-to-enable-wsgipassauthorization-for-django

Comment: for ubuntu there seems no `httpd.conf`. so you have to add `WSGIPassAuthorization On` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: I was confused by an issue where my requests from Postman were working from my localhost but not when sent to the live server. Your comment solved my issue.

Comment: Solved My problem, I was able to get data via api on my localhost, but when deployed on server over https:// it was giving me same error.

Comment: Is this true only in production or for local development as well?

Comment: Not sure for local development on Apache, I'm using Django development server locally

Comment: Thanks for this, been getting a headache from this issue and this solved my problem

Comment: I had this same issue when testing with pytest

Comment: You may also add the same line into a site conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` if you use multiple virtual hosts.

Answer (score 47):

This help me out without "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES" in my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Comment: The `SessionAuthentication` was what fixed it for me

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Wonder why the Django tutorial on this doesn't mention it. See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/ .

Comment: has any one figured out why it behaves like this? session on a mobile device has to do nothing with having a jwt token in the header of the request !! I am surprised by this solution after 5 hours of digging.

Comment: The SessionAuthentication works for me, too. Now I understand why my code didn't work.

Answer (score 26):

Just for other people landing up here with same error, this issue can arise if  your `request.user` is `AnonymousUser` and not the right user who is actually authorized to access the URL. You can see that by printing value of `request.user` . If it is indeed an anonymous user, these steps might help:

1. Make sure you have  `'rest_framework.authtoken'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.
2. Make sure you have this somewhere in `settings.py`:

   ```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {

        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
            # ...
        ),

        # ...
    }
   ```
3. Make sure you have the correct token for the user who is logged in.
   Basically, you need to do a `POST` request to a view which gives you the token if you provide the correct username and password. Example:

   ```
    curl -X POST -d "user=Pepe&password=aaaa"  http://localhost:8000/
   ```
4. Make sure the view which you are trying to access, has these:

   ```
    class some_fancy_example_view(ModelViewSet): 
    """
    not compulsary it has to be 'ModelViewSet' this can be anything like APIview etc, depending on your requirements.
    """
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
        authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,) 
        # ...
   ```
5. Use `curl` now this way:

   ```
    curl -X (your_request_method) -H  "Authorization: Token <your_token>" <your_url>
   ```

Example:

```
    curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8001/expenses/  -H "Authorization: Token 9463b437afdd3f34b8ec66acda4b192a815a15a8"
```

Comment: How can one print `request.user`? It appears that the POST method of a class-based view is never getting processed. Where else can I try to print the user?

Comment: user has to be authenticated to be able to being getting set in request object. Otherwise it just prints anonymous user. How are you authenticating your user ?

Answer (score 20):

If you are playing around in the command line (using curl, or HTTPie etc) you can use BasicAuthentication to test/user your API

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',  # enables simple command line authentication
            'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        )
    }
```

You can then use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/')

```
curl --user user:password -X POST http://example.com/path/ --data "some_field=some data"
```

or [httpie](https://httpie.org/) (its easier on the eyes):

```
http -a user:password POST http://example.com/path/ some_field="some data"
```

or something else like [Advanced Rest Client (ARC)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: BasicAuthentication is not simple command line authentication

Answer (score 18):

For me, I had to prepend my Authorization header with "JWT" instead of "Bearer" or "Token" on Django DRF. Then it started working.
eg -

`Authorization: JWT asdflkj2ewmnsasdfmnwelfkjsdfghdfghdv.wlsfdkwefojdfgh`

Comment: Same here. Using Next.JS with Django DRF as backend.

Comment: Agreed. Trying django with react for the first time and your answer helped me.

Answer (score 16):

I was having this problem with postman.Add this to the headers...
[image]

Comment: In my case, I had not selected the checkbox... :) Thanks, this gave me the clue

Comment: I am using thunder client (extension for VS code) to check my API. The checkbox is authomatically checked when we add a new header of field or whatever.  So this never came in my mind. But after seeing this answer, i unchecked the checkbox and then checked that again and that worked. Thanks..

Comment: I forgotten to add the "Token " prefix, careful guys

Answer (score 12):

I too faced the same since I missed adding

> authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)

in my API view class.

```
class ServiceList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
```

In addition to the above, we need to explicitly tell Django about the **Authentication** in settings.py file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
   'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it worked for me.

*In settings.py*

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
     ....
     ...
     # Use JWT 
     'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
     # 'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
     ....
     ...
}
```

*Add this too*

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ....
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
    ..
}
```

Comment: thank you so much)) worked with only `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',`

Answer (score 4):

Adding `SessionAuthentication` in `settings.py` will do the job

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ( 
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if anyone come here from [Full Stack React & Django [5] - Django Token Authentication - Traversy Media](https://youtu.be/0d7cIfiydAc) So you need to something like this

accounts/api.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import LoginSerializer, RegisterSerializer, UserSerializer
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication

# Register Api


class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })

# Login Api


class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })

# Get User Api


class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case TokenAuthentication was missing

```
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
```

I changed it to below and it worked

```
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is session Login so you need to provide you credentials
so do 
`127.0.0:8000/admin`
admin and login later it will work fine

Comment: Sorry, but this question is already answered with more detail than yours...

Comment: This is for the people who need quick solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `authentication_classes` then you should have `is_active` as `True` in `User` model, which might be `False` by default.

Comment: what are the authentication classes?

Comment: How do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that the Authorization Token / API key is actually valid. The `Authentication credentials were not provided.` error message seems to be what's returned by the API if the key is invalid as well (I encountered this when I accidently used the wrong API key).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a CDN, check that the CDN doesn't remove the request header when if forwards the request to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I added this in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
],}
```

and I created a superuser and created a token using:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and created a token using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/` and nothing else and it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had strange issue for this error.

I was getting Token correctly and was passing Authorization token correctly in Postman and was still getting this error

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I searched it on internet and check many SO questions. But nothing worked.

Then i closed Postman application and restart it again then it worked. I had no idea why Postman was behaving like that.

Thankfully problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with postman and django backend. I used to use `Bearer token` but it started failing, I had to manually add the `Authorization` Header on `Headers` while prepending it with `Token` ie `Token token`

Answer (score 0):

I'd also add that for those looking to implement **Token only** authentication. Ensure that your ViewSet's have the "authentication_classes" attribute.

For example:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication

class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     """
     Tasks for the current user. This endpoint allows tasks to be viewed or edited. 
     """
     queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
     serializer_class = TaskSerializer
     authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
     permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

This will bypass the requirement for the users Username and Password to be required in the sessions request.

Answer (score 0):

This also worked on my end

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

views.py

```
class CheckUser(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTTokenUserAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        return Response({'message': f'Hello, {user.username}!'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```