# How to enable WSGIPassAuthorization for Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I am testing my Django API endpoints but I need to enable WSGIPassAuthorization to let Authorization header be received. Where should I enable it?

PS: I am on macOS, but any answer might be useful!

Comment: In your apache config

Comment: But I never setup any apache configuration. Is it done by default? Where are these configurations to edit them?

Comment: So how do you use mod_wsgi

Comment: O am not using it, but it seems that I need it to activate this option

Comment: Yeah.. I'll write an answer.. Please accept it

Comment: Are you using Apache ``Server.app`` version of mod_wsgi? Or are you using ``mod_wsgi-express``? They are the only ways of using mod_wsgi on macOS where you wouldn't have had to configure Apache yourself. If you are using ``mod_wsgi-express``, directly or via Django ``runmodwsgi``, then that directive is set by default.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `mod_wsgi`, just install apache and use it inside your VirtualHost.

And then: `WSGIPassAuthorization On`

Answer (score 3):

You have to go to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled where your configuration file sits either the one with SSL certificates or the one without and add `WSGIPassAuthorization On` where the file ends.