# Django API works locally but not when deployed on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm working with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Django Rest Framework JWT](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/), but I'm running into an issue in regards to local behavior vs external behavior.

When I make a `POST` request to get a JWT token, everything works as desired **both locally and on my EC2 instance**. However, once I have the token, when I make a request to my server that requires authentication, only my local server returns the expected response. On my **deployed** server, I get the following error:

`{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

What I've tried so far:

Editing `http.conf` by sshing into my server and enabling `WSGIPathAuthorization`. (saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided) and tried the solution)

What could be causing this behavior? My local machine and my deployed code are identical, leading me to believe that this has something to do with server-side configuration.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply restarting Apache after enabling WSGPPathAuthorization fixed my error. For those of you who encounter something similar, here's what I did:

1. SSH into the server
2. Navigate to where your `http.conf` file is stored (in Apache, this is usually 
   `etc/httpd/http.conf`)
3. Edit `http.conf`, adding `WSGIPathAuthorization On`.
4. Restart Apache by running `sudo service httpd restart`.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned ElasticBeanstalk.

You can add this to your container commands which will be executed during deployment.

```
01_wsgipass:
 command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when you do configure **wsgi** with **apache** on ***EC2*** instance.
Bascially its the problem in apache configuration,
it has nothing to do with ***AWS EC2***.
As **apache** bydefault do not process *Authorization* headers, so in order to make that happen we need to configure its files.
For ubuntu

```
cd /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

paste the following line

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```