# Credential error when trying to preserve data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am developing an api in Django Rest Framework, which at the moment only registers new users, but I have a problem and that is that now I am adding a bit of security, which is being controlled by means of tokens, but at the time of entering the token of an authenticated user for the creation of users generates an error of The authentication credentials were not provided, but I send the token as follows: 
This is plugin rest client visual studio code 
My authentication:

```
### Login user
POST http://localhost:8000/auth-token/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "hamel",
    "password": "contraseña"
}
```

This return a token b6773c67ecb940ae4fb7c9d49466a01fd46f5eb4 
My register of user:

```
### Create User
POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users
Authorization: Token b6773c67ecb940ae4fb7c9d49466a01fd46f5eb4
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "first_name": "Carlos",
    "last_name": "Carlos",
    "username": "carlos",
    "email": "correo@rgrgr.com",
    "password": "contraseña",
    "password2": "contraseña"
}
```

My setting.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

This my views.py:

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'profiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

This is my MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

This my urls main:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from users.views import CustomToken

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth-token/', CustomToken.as_view()),
    path('api/v1/', include('users.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
)
```

This my urls app users:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users', views.CreateUser.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: maybe one of these might help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided)

Comment: Can you show your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARES`?

Comment: @seif When the problem arose, it was one of the first pages I saw, but that solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I have modified the question

Comment: Can you try change the plugin you use and try postman or curl any thing maybe the problem is in the plugin ?

Comment: Or try deferent user token

Comment: Can you also share your `urls.py`?

Comment: @GwynBleidD I have added the urls

Comment: @seif with the other tools it gives me the same result

Comment: Everything look right I can't find the problem may be try comment this middle ware  `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` maybe it's related to the problem

Comment: Are you using a custom token system ??

Comment: @seif It is just the example from the documentation on creating tokens, I just wanted to know the process from behind, I will have to inspect line by line of my application to check the error, thanks for your time.

Comment: I've tried to recreate your issue with no luck. Can you maybe share your full project?

Comment: @GwynBleidD this my project https://github.com/HamelBarrer/wrike_server

Comment: I've just tested your project and it works properly. Please try making this request using some other tool, like curl or postman as I'm pretty sure the VSCode plugin is here to blame.

Comment: @GwynBleidD thank you very much, i thought my application was wrong, now just switch to postman, thanks for your time