# Django rest framework : creating a user ask for authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-viewsets

I was using django user, authentication and permission modules but while making a request to create a new user in the POST request, its asking for authentication.

[image]

and I am getting

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Here is my **serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {
                'write_only':True,
                'required': True
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user) # create token for the user
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOfObject]
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename = 'users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)), 
]
```

Comment: i think you are having the same problem with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided).
Hope it helps

Comment: my question is different because I am using viewsets along with the user model of django to create the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because permission_classes you set include IsAuthenticated. If you want to make it public with user creation like below example code, then custom Permission class has to be implemented that allows it.

```
class CustomizedUserPermission(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'create':
            return True
        return super().has_permission(request, view)  
      
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    permission_classes = [CustomizedUserPermission, ]
```

updated to override get_permissions class in ViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_permissions(self): 
        if self.action == 'create': 
                return [] 
        return super().get_permissions()
```

Comment: any solution without creating another custom class

Comment: I already have custom permission class `class IsOwnerOfObject(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        return obj == request.user`

can it be possible to do something here

Comment: You can override get_permissions method in ViewSet class to exclude dynamically permissions by request action then !

Comment: how exactly can I do that?

Comment: With create action, any other authenticated or object-having permissions should be remove. please refer to updated answer.

Comment: when its not a create request, why are we returning `super().get_permissions()` shouldn't it be the permission classes that I am using?

Comment: also I am getting `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'action'`

Comment: Can you try with modifying self.request.action to self.action ?

Comment: If it is not for create action, then viewsets will apply other permissions that you declared as permission_classes, which is represented as return super().get_permissions().