# Make user activation ApiView open DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have this APIView to activate a user:

```py
class UserActivationView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ([])
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    """ 
    Intermediate view to activate a user's email. 
    """
    def get (self, request, uid, token):
        protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
        web_url = protocol + request.get_host()
        post_url = web_url + "/auth/users/activate/"
        post_data = {'uid': uid, 'token': token}
        result = requests.post(post_url, data = post_data)
        content = result.text
        return Response(content)
```

I need to access it from a link in an email sent using `Djoser`

But I get this error when accessing the APIView:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

"{\"detail\":\"Authentication credentials were not provided.\"}"
```

View path in users:

```py
path('activate-user/<str:uid>/<str:token>/',  views.UserActivationView.as_view()),
```

The urlConf:

```py
# Register API
apipatterns = [
    path('', include('activities.urls')),
    path('', include('social_auth.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth-token/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

]
```

DRF options:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework - Authentication credentials were not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906630/django-rest-framework-authentication-credentials-were-not-provided)

Comment: I don't think so, I updated the question with `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` used in the project, What I want is to access this endpoint with no authentication

Answer (score 0):

I can access the endpoint with no credentials using this code:

```py
class UserActivationView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [] #disables authentication
    permission_classes = [] #disables permission
    """ 
    Intermediate view to activate a user's email. 
    """
    def get (self, request, uid, token):
        protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
        web_url = protocol + request.get_host()
        post_url = web_url + "/auth/users/activation/"
        post_data = {'uid': uid, 'token': token}
        result = requests.post(post_url, data = post_data)
        content = result.text
        return Response(content)
```

The other error blocking the request is using a wrong `Djoser` activation url

it's: `/auth/users/activation/`

not: `/auth/users/activate/` I used before